# Azure Batch - python ServicePrincipalCredentials equivalent

Tags: azure-batch

What is the equivalent of the following python code in C#?

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

creds = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
        secret=AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        tenant=AZURE_CLIENT_TENANT,
        resource="https://batch.core.windows.net/")
```

I tried:

```
var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(accountSettings.TenantId, accountSettings.ClientId, accountSettings.ClientSecret);
var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { ".default" }));
var batchClient = new BatchServiceClient(new TokenCredentials(token.Token));
```

or

```
var tokenCredentials = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{accountSettings.TenantId}", accountSettings.ClientId, accountSettings.ClientSecret);
var batchClient = new BatchServiceClient(tokenCredentials);

using (BatchClient client = BatchClient.Open(batchClient)) {...}
```

but each time I call `CommitAsync()`, I get "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'".

if I use

```
var credential = new ClientCredential(accountSettings.ClientId, accountSettings.ClientSecret);
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{accountSettings.TenantId}");
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://batch.core.windows.net/", credential);
var batchClient = new BatchServiceClient(new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken));
```

or

```
var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(accountSettings.TenantId, accountSettings.ClientId, accountSettings.ClientSecret);
var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { $"https://batch.core.windows.net/.default" }));
var batchServiceClient = new BatchServiceClient(new TokenCredentials(token.Token));
```

I get "Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'" (MissingRequiredProperty, Property=type, A required property was not specified in the request body.)
Callstack:
at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.PoolOperations.d__6.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.BatchRequestBase`2.<ExecuteRequestWithCancellationAsync>d__42.MoveNext() at Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.BatchRequestBase`2.d__40.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I needed to add containerConfig.Type = "dockerCompatible";